# Why is $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(2+\cos x)^2} = \frac{4}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{(z^2+4z+1)^2} \, dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In a solved exercise, the textbook I'm reading states $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(2+\cos x)^2} = \frac{4}{i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{(z^2+4z+1)^2} \, dz$ without offering any explanation. Why is this equality obvious?

Comment: Let $z=e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call it "obvious" but the equality is based on a standard trick from an application of complex residues which you can find, for example, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_3_%E2%80%93_trigonometric_integrals).

After the complex substitution

- $\cos x = \frac 12\left(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}\right)$ and $z= e^{ix}$ your integral looks like

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(2+\cos x)^2} = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac 1{\left(2+\frac 12\left(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}\right)\right)^2}\cdot \frac{ie^{ix}}{ie^{ix}}dx$$ $$\stackrel{z=e^{ix}}{=}\oint_{|z|=1}\underbrace{\frac{1}{\left(2+\frac 12\left(z + \frac 1z\right)\right)^2}\frac{1}{iz}}_{=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{4z+z^2+1}{2z}\right)^2}\frac{1}{iz} = \frac{4z}{i(z^2+4z+1)^2}}dz$$